# Javascript Regex Search on a string

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding creating a regex search on a string. The code is in javascript, I am having problem with searching using this regex

```
var string = 'string [something]';
  var regex = new RegExp(string,'g');
```

Whenever i try to use search() method on a bigger string i.e (searching for the above string on  a bigger string) i get an Syntax error SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /string [something]/: Range out of order in character class

Comment: what is the string on which you are testing and what should be your expected result?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The regex string is not valid because '[' and ']' are reserved expressions.  You need to escape them

`var string = 'string \\[something\\]';`

[TEST: click here](https://regexr.com/675bd)

Comment: Good call Andreas... i think he needs to double escape. I've updated answer